# faster alternatives to solve()

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse

If `chol2inv(chol(matrix))` is not applicable to my matrix (not a positive-definite square matrix), is there any other alternative methods in R to do matrix inversion (or avoiding the inversion). I am attempting to invert matrices of size 10K by 10K to 15K by 15K in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: What are you inverting them for? What's next after inversion? Is there any special structure to the problem (e.g. low rank, sparseness, ... )?

Comment: the inversion is part of the end result so they have to be inverted; they aren't sparse, all elements are populated in fact (e.g. gene expression matrix).

Comment: What is a "reasonable amount of time"? In your question you mention avoiding inversion (which is a good idea), but in a comment you say that you actually need the inverted matrix as a result?

Comment: hi thanks for the response! by avoid inverse i meant avoid using solve(), sorry. the chol2inv  approach is much faster when applicable but I need an approach that is applicable when the matrix is not positive-definite square matrix. Also there is the memory consideration in R. So if you know of memory and matrix packages / functions that enable the inversion(by whatever method) of a 10K by 10K matrix in R that would be awesome

Comment: Until you give some specific properties of your matrix, this is very broad and somewhat off-topic. Also, I can't imagine what you need the inverse for.